# DIV images doesn't show in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have two animated `.gif` images in my webpage, but they are not being displayed in Firefox. It works on IE, Safari and Chrome. I have read other posts but I couldn't find a solution that works. Could someone help please?

This is the url:
http://www.lokalbericht.unibe.ch

Following is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Lokalbericht - Hermann Burger</title>
<style type="text/css">
.text_body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
}
body {
    background-color:#000000;
    background-image:url(images/intro/background_paper.jpg);
    background-position:center 50px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;

}
div.soon {
    content:url(images/intro/coming_soon.gif);
    position: relative;
    width:650px;
    height:170px;
    top:350px;
    left:30%;
}

div.lokalbericht {
    content:url(images/intro/animation.gif);
    width:160px; 
    height:20px;
    position: absolute;
    top:300px;
    left:45%;

}​​
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="soon"> &nbsp;</div>
<div class="lokalbericht">&nbsp;</div>
```

​

Comment: `content:url(images/intro/animation.gif);` - why not just set it as the background image, using `background:url()`

Comment: You can't use `content` unless it's with a pseudo-element

Comment: Thanks Nick R. This the right solution

Answer (score 0):

I checked your link. Try this...

```
div.soon {
background-image:url(images/intro/coming_soon.gif);
position: relative;
width:650px;
height:170px;
top:350px;
left:30%;
}
div.lokalbericht {
background-image:url(images/intro/animation.gif);
width:160px; 
height:20px;
position: absolute;
top:300px;
left:45%;
}​​
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

**content:** css property which you have set for load background image  is creating problem so just replaced it with **background-image** into both given class **div.soon** ,**div.lokalbericht**

```
 background-image:url(images/intro/coming_soon.gif);
 background-image:url(images/intro/animation.gif);
```

In place of :

```
content:url(images/intro/coming_soon.gif);
```

I hope this helps you!!

Comment: I am glad to here that i could help you. you can vote up my answer as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't support the content property in the same way as Chrome — on img elements and/or when the source is an image.

So you need to use background property instead of content or you need to use :before property the classes like below.

```
div.soon:before {
content:url(images/intro/coming_soon.gif);
position: relative;
width:650px;
height:170px;
top:350px;
left:30%;
}

div.lokalbericht:before {
content:url(images/intro/animation.gif);
width:160px; 
height:20px;
position: absolute;
top:300px;
left:45%;

}​​
```